# MFC application launch fails with "DLL Initialization Failed" after adding a new dialog

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-7

I am working on a legacy MFC application which is used to review result files.
This is built as 64-bit code.

My problem is that on adding Dialog to one of the project, the application fails to launch with error:[The program '[102276] APP.exe' has exited with code -1073741502 (0xc0000142) 'DLL Initialization Failed'.]

Even after deleting the dialog and removing all related references in resource files, the application again fails with 'DLL Initialization Failed' error.

I would be grateful for all the help that I can get.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Existing project was developed in VS 2010. Currently build environment is VS 2013.
On adding new dialog, resource file (.rc) got updated. However, the following piece of code was missing on the generated file.

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU) 
 #ifdef _WIN32 
 LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US 
 #pragma code_page(1252) 
 #endif //_WIN32

#include "res\(ResourceFile).rc2"  // non-Microsoft Visual C++ edited resources
 #endif

Adding the above line resolved the issue.